# $.ajax error on mobile safari

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile-safari

This is weird.

Only on mobile safari, and since last night this script....

```
 function login(login) 
{
        scrollTo(0,0);      
        var persistent = 'false'
            if ($('#persistent').is(':checked')){persistent = 'true';}
            if ($('#loginMsg').is(":visible")) {$('#loginMsg').hide();}
            var password = $('#password').val(); 
            var email = $('#email').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "rpc.php",
        data: { id: email, value: password, persistent: persistent, method: "loginM"},      
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 5000,
        success:    function(data){

        if (data.login=='true')
            {
            $('#pleaseWait').jqmShow(); 
            location.reload(true);
            }           
        else
            {   
            $("#loginMsg").show();
            $("#loginMsg").html(data.status);   
            }   
        },  
        /* error: function() {
        alert('This is taking too long. You could try again now, or wait and try again later.');*/ 

        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
               alert(xhr.statusText);      
    }
});
}
```

1. `alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);` - returns me the entire script for the page
2. `alert(textStatus);` - returns 'ok'
3. `alert(errorThrown);` - returns '200'

When I run the script it errors immediately, doesn't wait 5 seconds. I have quarantined the script so it is by itself so other scripts don't interfere with it. Cleared the cache on the ipod.

This seems quite a common problem. One solution seems to be rebooting the sever which isn't an option.

Comment: The URL is relative shouldn't it be absolute like : http://myserver.com/rpc.php ?

Comment: That has fixed it, strange as I have a another function immediately beneath that works perfectly with a relative URL. You should post a response so I can give you some cred.

Comment: Okay here is the answer :) Have a nice evening maxum!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL is relative. It should be absolute like : http://myserver.com/rpc.php